# Как разобрать произвольную ссылку на составляющие

Tags: javascript, jquery

Как можно получить имя домена и прочие компоненты из посторонней ссылки?

Comment: ассоциация: https://stackoverflow.com/q/736513

Answer (score 6):

```
var parser = document.createElement('a');
parser.href = "http://example.com:3000/pathname/?search=test#hash";

parser.protocol; // => "http:"
parser.hostname; // => "example.com"
parser.port;     // => "3000"
parser.pathname; // => "/pathname/"
parser.search;   // => "?search=test"
parser.hash;     // => "#hash"
parser.host;     // => "example.com:3000"
```

[Источник](https://gist.github.com/jlong/2428561)

Answer (score 4):

Боле современный способ — использование объекта [URL](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/URL). Этот глобальный объект доступен в популярных веб-обозревателях: Edge, Firefox, Chrome, Safari, Opera, а также на мобильных платформах (кроме Opera Mini). В Node.js этот объект находится в стандартном модуле [url](https://nodejs.org/api/url.html).

```
var link = new URL("https://mymedia:qwerty@ru.stackoverflow.com:8080/p/a/t/h?query=string#qqq");
console.log(link.protocol);  // "https:"
console.log(link.username);  // "mymedia"
console.log(link.password);  // "qwerty"
console.log(link.host);      // "ru.stackoverflow.com:8080"
console.log(link.hostname);  // "ru.stackoverflow.com"
console.log(link.port);      // 8080
console.log(link.path);      // "/p/a/t/h?query=string" (только в Node.js)
console.log(link.pathname);  // "/p/a/t/h"
console.log(link.search);    // "?query=string"
console.log(link.query);     // "query=string" (только в Node.js)
console.log(link.hash);      // "qqq"
```